# How to rollback both database data when you are using Jdbc template with batch update if any error coming into one of your database execution query?

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions, batch-updates

I have two datasource and i am using jdbctemplate batch update to update data in a batch but i am having one issue that whenever i am getting error in one of datasource in batch update than how we can rollback that inserted data from other datasource?

Service.java

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)`
public void saveDataInBatch() {`
List<List<Customer>> mainCustomerList = getMainCustomerList();`
List<List<Address>> mainAddressList = getMainAddressList();`

        for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
            saveData(mainCustomerList,mainAddressList,index);
        }
    }
    
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    private void saveData(List<List<Customer>> mainCustomerList, List<List<Address>> mainAddressList, int index) {
        customerRepository.saveSuccessBatch(mainCustomerList.get(index));
        addressRepository.saveSuccessBatch(mainAddressList.get(index));
    }`
```

CustomerRepository.java

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public int[] saveSuccessBatch(List<Customer> customerList) {
return jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("insert into customer (age,first_name, last_name) values(?,?,?)",
new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
@Override
public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
Customer customer = customerList.get(i);
ps.setInt(1, customer.getAge());
ps.setString(2, customer.getFirstName());
ps.setString(3, customer.getLastName());
}

                    @Override
                    public int getBatchSize() {
                        return customerList.size();
                    }
                });
    }
```

AddressRepository.java

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public int[] saveSuccessBatch(List<Address> addressList) {
return jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("insert into address (city,street, zipCode) values(?,?,?)",
new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
@Override
public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
Address address = addressList.get(i);
ps.setString(1, address.getCity());
ps.setString(2, address.getStreet());
ps.setInt(3, address.getZipCode());
}

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return addressList.size();
            }
            });
}
```

I am expecting to sync data into both the table of customer and address.

Comment: Did you try `rollbackFor` along with `propagation` in `@ Transactional`?

Comment: @KeshavramKuduwa yes i already tried